# Is it OK to create a property from a class?

Tags: python, properties

I'd like to ask if there could be a hidden catch in the following usage of `@property`. It passed all tests but it is an unusual combination.

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = False

    @property
    class enable:
        def __init__(self, block):
            self._block = block
            self._saved = None

        def __enter__(self):
            block = self._block
            self._saved = block.enabled
            block.enabled = True
            return block

        def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
            self._block.enabled = self._saved

# example
b = Block()
print(b.enabled)
with b.enable:
    print(b.enabled)
print(b.enabled)
```

UPDATE: despite the example the context manager will be used exclusively in the internal code, e.g. `with self._enable: ...`. It won't be a part of the API.

Comment: That's the most confusing use of `@property` I've ever seen. It's going to take a while for anyone maintaining this to figure out what it does and whether it's correct.

Comment: And what is the point? Why not make the Block class into the context manager directly?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I would guess so `Block` could also support `with b.disable`, though that's a guess, and I still would choose a different design personally.

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Comment: @DanielRoseman This context manager is intended for internal use in the Block class itself only.